# Is this intel pipelining instruction?

Tags: assembly, intel, x86-16, disassembly, pipelining

In my knowledge, `intel 8086 pipelining` is technique
that fetching the ***next instruction*** when the present instruction is being executed.

[This](https://www.quora.com/What-is-pipelining-in-8086-microprocessor) article said that one of ***Advantage of pipelining*** is
***eliminates the waiting time of EU and speeds up the processing***.

I think, instructions like `lea 0x7(%eax), %ecx` can be split into several instructions,
like `add $0x7, %eax; lea %eax, %ecx`.

***My think)***
So, by definition,
I think above example matches the definition of `intel 8086 pipelining`
because it executes **several instructions at one time slot** and
so operation like this **speeds up the processing**.

***Question)***
I'm curious about the below instructions can be the example of pipelining.

```
main:
 mov $0x2, %eax
 mov $0x3, %esi
 lea (%eax), %ecx           # result: 2. Pipeling?
 lea 0x7(%eax), %ecx        # result: 9. Pipeling?
 lea 0x7(%eax,%esi,), %ecx  # result: 12. Pipeling?
 lea 0x7(,%esi,4), %ecx     # result: 19. Pipeling?
 lea 0x7(%eax,%esi,4), %ecx # result: 21. Pipeling?
```

Comment: Pipelining is a feature of the cpu it's not applicable to single instructions.

Comment: and is not specific to intel or the x86, it is widely used.

Comment: although I dont think the 8086 used it, it had a small prefetch buffer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first computers were not pipelined. They fetched an instruction, executed all the cycles required by the instructions and passed to the next instruction. On the average an instruction required 5-6 cycles.
This behavior was true for all computers up to, mid 80's, including the 8086 (introduced in 78).

In the late seventies, people discovered that pipeline was an efficient way to improve efficiency. The first commercial chip was IBM 801, but success of pipeline was with Sun Sparc, Berkeley Risc and MIPS, in the mid eighties.

The idea is to split all instructions in similar stages, and to associate this stages to independent HW resources, in such a way that you can start a new instruction, without waiting for the previous one to complete, allowing to start a new instruction per cycle. To deal with instruction interaction (hazards), it is more 1 instruction every ~1.5 cycles, but the gain vs the previous generation is huge (X3 performances).

The problem is that pipelining requires specific instructions sets, based on simple data movement (called RISC instruction sets). New computers were based on this scheme, but older processors instruction sets were not adapted (including x86).

To profit from the pipeline benefit, while keeping upward compatibility, intel decided to have a microarchitecture based on two part: the first one fetches x86 instructions and translates them to pipelinable ones (called μOps) and the second one is a pipeline execution of these μOps. This was first introduced with Pentium Pro (introduced in 1995) and is present in any successive versions.

The code that you give

> lea 0x7(%eax), %ecx

translated to

> add $0x7, %eax;
>   lea %eax, %ecx

is an example of μOps translation. Translation is peculiarly useful do convert ALU operations with an in-memory operand to simpler operations performing a single task (memory transfer or ALU op).

Presently all computers are pipelined (except some simple μcontrolers or some processors embedded in FPGA).

*Whatever* sequence of instructions that you give will be executed in pipeline, including of course the ones in your question. The only limitation is that depending on instruction interactions, there can be hazards that may imply a slowdown (stall) of the pipeline.

> I think above example matches the definition of intel 8086 pipelining

Pipeline is a characteristic of a microarchitecture, not of an instruction set. So the microarchitecture 8086 was NOT pipeline, but subsequent architectural implementations of its instruction set (called x86 or IA32) are.

> because it executes several instructions at one time slot

You are actually right and several instructions can be started at one time slot, but this is another technique above pipeline allowing parallel execution at the instruction level and called superscalar.

Comment: Original 8086 pipelines instruction prefetch, with a 6 byte buffer.  This is really easy to implement compared to pipelining decode / execute / etc, but it's still pipelining that some even earlier CPUs didn't have.

Comment: PPro (first-gen P6 family) was the first to decode x86 instructions into RISC-like uops.  486 and Pentium just pipelined x86 instructions when possible, making it more efficient to use more but simpler x86 instructions (e.g. avoiding memory-destination `add [mem], reg`, because even though it can pair in either pipe, it takes 3 cycles before another (pair of) instruction(s) can start to execute.)  Also avoiding push/pop was sometimes good on P5 Pentium.  But mostly that was good for P6 before they added a stack engine to get rid of the stack-pointer update uops, while P5 could pair push/pop.

Comment: Splitting LEA into ADD and LEA (I guess actually MOV?) is hardly a good example.  It's that sort of idea, but that decoding doesn't even make sense (it modifies the original EAX), and shift+add is not hard so LEA is always a single uop on all CPUs that decode complex instructions to multiple uops.  A better example is a memory-destination add, which is load + add + store.

Comment: Yes, pipelined vs. non-pipelined is an implementation decision.  But some ISAs explicitly expose some of the pipelining.  e.g. branch-delay slots on MIPS and some other RISCs, and especially early MIPS load delay slots (using the result of a load in the next instruction gives unpredictable results; the first-gen MIPS CPU hardware doesn't interlock for the dependency, so the ISA leaves that undefined).  Also, the Mill has delayed loads only write their destination register after some number of other instructions.  (So you can expose ILP to an in-order pipeline.)

Comment: See Agner Fog's microarch pdf (https://agner.org/optimize/) for details on the pipeline in P5 Pentium vs. P6, and vs. in-order Atom.  (In-order Atom (not Silvermont) does decode to uops, unlike in-order P5.)

Comment: Thanks for all these precisions. Updated the answer.